# RewriteRule lang and page parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried all the solutions proposed in this site, but nothing worked.

This is what I did:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

In essence, I want access the page in this format:

```
website.com/en
website.com/en/download
website.com/download
```

and translate to:

```
website.com/index.php?lang=en
website.com/index.php?lang=en&page=download
website.com/index.php?page=download
```

Any Solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and last rules are just fine, but for the last option - a page without a language folder - you should simply redirect it to index.php and make sure there isn't another reiteration, in the following way

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the following rules on my dev server and they appear to achieve what you want.

```
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

In the script `/folder/index.php` for testing:

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Example urls:

```
https://localhost/en/
    ->  Array ( [lang] => en )

https://localhost/download/
    ->  Array ( [page] => download ) 

https://localhost/en/download/
    ->  Array ( [lang] => en [page] => download )
```